# is there shortcut method called insert_or_update in AppEngine (or perhaps in Django)? Why not?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, insert-update

I repeat this kind of pattern many times: (and I think isn't this common?)

**Google App Engine**

```
# Insert if object doesn't exist, Otherwise Update Object
obj = get_or_insert('123', title='Hello World')
obj.title = 'Hello World'
obj.puts()
```

**Django**

```
# Insert if object doesn't exist, Otherwise Update Object
obj, created = Model.objects.get_or_create(id='123', 
                   defaults={'title':'Hello World'}
if not created:
    obj.title = 'Hello World'
    obj.save()
```

It would be good **if** I **could** just call `insert_or_update`. isn't it? e.g:

```
# AppEngine
obj = insert_or_update('123', title='Hello World')

# Django
obj = Model.objects.insert_or_update(id='123', defaults={'title': 'Hello World'})
```

## UPDATE

Back to App Engine [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass#Model_get_or_insert), I found the snippet on what this `get_or_insert` method doing. Something like the following:

```
def txn(key_name, **kwds):
    entity = Story.get_by_key_name(key_name, parent=kwds.get('parent'))
    if entity is None:
        entity = Story(key_name=key_name, **kwds)
        entity.put()
    return entity

def get_or_insert(key_name, **kwargs):
    return db.run_in_transaction(txn, key_name, **kwargs)

get_or_insert('some key', title="The Three Little Pigs")
```

I was wondering why a `insert_or_update` method not being created in both app engine and django.

### App Engine Workaround

```
@classmethod
def insert_or_update(cls, key_name, parent=None, **kwargs):
    def _tx():
        entity = cls.get_by_key_name(key_name, parent=parent)
        if entity:
            for key in kwargs:
                setattr(entity, key, kwargs[key])
        else:
            entity = cls(key_name=key_name, parent=parent, **kwargs)
        entity.put()
        return entity
    return db.run_in_transaction(_tx)
```

### Django Solution

[See Below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20430268/764592)

Comment: You're talking about an UPSERT operation that returns the value I believe. Django doesn't support such a function AFAIK.

Comment: Recently there was a commit that's relevant to this problem, https://github.com/django/django/commit/6272d

Comment: @MattDeacalionStevens, Finally. That would be on Django 1.7, :-)

Comment: Yeah… a while to go yet, but you were right on the mark. :-)

Answer (score 1):

## Django

[**update_or_create**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) (from Django official documentation)

```
update_or_create(defaults=None, **kwargs)
```

*New in Django 1.7 version.*

A convenience method for updating an object with the given `kwargs`, creating a new one if necessary. The `defaults` is a dictionary of (field, value) pairs used to update the object.

Returns a tuple of `(object, created)`, where `object` is the created or updated object and `created` is a boolean specifying whether a new object was created.

The `update_or_create` method tries to fetch an object from database based on the given `kwargs`. If a match is found, it updates the fields passed in the `defaults` dictionary.

This is meant as a shortcut to boilerplatish code. For example:

```
try:
    obj = Person.objects.get(first_name='John', last_name='Lennon')
    for key, value in updated_values.iteritems():
        setattr(obj, key, value)
    obj.save()
except Person.DoesNotExist:
    updated_values.update({'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Lennon'})
    obj = Person(**updated_values)
    obj.save()
```

This pattern gets quite unwieldy as the number of fields in a model goes up. The above example can be rewritten using `update_or_create()` like so:

```
obj, created = Person.objects.update_or_create(
    first_name='John', last_name='Lennon', defaults=updated_values)
```

For detailed description how names passed in kwargs are resolved see [`get_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get_or_create).

As described above in [`get_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get_or_create), this method is prone to a race-condition which can result in multiple rows being inserted simultaneously if uniqueness is not enforced at the database level.

## AppEngine

Not so lucky yet, as Matt has mentioned earlier, it may not be a common use case. Perhaps in AppEngine it's not so much of such use case.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly:

```
obj, created = Model.objects.get_or_create(id='123', 
               defaults={'title':'Hello World'})
```

The above should be replaced by the following:

```
obj, created = Model.objects.get_or_create(foo='alpha', bar='beta' 
               defaults={'title':'Hello World'})
```

where *foo* and *bar* are fields in the model. This resolves the repetition for django. Unsure about appengine. HTH

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood my question. With your current answer, you get the object of the params you provided. The object.title may not be Hello World, So I also want to update that object with the title Hello World. So If you already have the object, update the title to Hello World. If you don't have the object, create the object with title Hello World. Put this in one liner shortcut methods, it would be, Model.objects.insert_or_update(foo='alpha', bar='beta', defaults={'title': 'Hello World'}); But I was thinking Why there's no such method, isn't it common use cases?

Comment: #your code required some additional lines to make it works as my requirement.; if not obj: obj.title = "Hello World; obj.save();

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not as common as you would think. Personally, I don't find myself having to do this very often and when I do it's only two or three lines longer than your proposed `insert_or_update` method and this isn't enough to make me cry out for this feature or to motivate me to add it myself. Although I have used MySQL's `INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` quite a lot in the past.

I've had this experience a few times myself, just a few weeks ago I was wondering why Django doesn't have a `toggle` method on M2M relationships… I ended up making one:

https://github.com/Matt-Stevens/django/commit/f7c36

## Edit

Django 1.7 looks like it will have this "***UPSERT***" ability, https://github.com/django/django/commit/6272d

Comment: Hmm... That's make sense,... Anyway, that's an interesting toggle features for M2M. +1 :-D